# Android studio xml preview only font issue

Tags: android, android-studio

While in design screen only the fonts are shown tiny in preview (image attached). But in original output it is looking correct. How to solve this?[image: screen image]

Answer (score 1):

in the preview to left of android api version you can choose your device i think you selected a device with large screen so your fonts looks tiny

Comment: Thanks Poorya, but even if i have selected any device it is showing like that. Not only in preview window also in design tab it looks tiny

Comment: take a full screen shot pls

Comment: screen shot changed

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by changing the theme in preview screen. I have attached the image for your reference it shows the App theme selection. I used the **AppTheme** to solve the issue